# ThreadPoolExecutor does not terminate but shutdownNow() returns an empty list

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, threadpoolexecutor

in some of my jUnit tests I create a ThreadPoolExecutor to test if my code does not have obvious concurrency errors. At the end of each such test I shutdown the executor and verify if all tasks were completed, similarly to the below code:

```java
// wait on a conditional that indicates that results are available
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(100l);
// do other result verifications here
if ( ! executor.isTerminated()) {
    final var stuckTasks = executor.shutdownNow();
    for (var stuckTask: stuckTasks) log.severe("stuck " + stuckTask);
    fail("executor not terminated, " + stuckTasks.size() + " tasks remaining");
}
```

If I run these tests in a loop, every few hours I get a failure with message "*executor not terminated, **0** tasks remaining*"

Is it normal and can be safely ignored or does it mean that my code has some concurrency errors in fact?
Apart from unfinished tasks, are there any other possible reasons for executor to not terminate?

I'd like to emphasize that it has **NEVER** happened for the number of remaining tasks to be nonzero (even after running the tests in a loop for more than 12 hours, where a single run takes about 2s) and all other verifications pass correctly, which would be impossible if any of the tasks submitted to this executor actually got stuck.
100ms that I await for termination is a lot in this case as all the submitted tasks take less than 10ms **and** they are all supposed to be finished even before `awaitTermination(100l)` is called as results were already available.

I'm using openJdk-11 on ubuntu in case it matters.

The code in question is [here](https://github.com/morgwai/grpc-utils/blob/9ddcc5b284fa0d1eb73bc173b375281fe488f2c4/src/test/java/pl/morgwai/base/grpc/utils/ConcurrentRequestObserverTest.java#L532) if anyone is interested (I have since modified it to fail only if the number of remaining tasks is nonzero, as so far it seems harmless). Failure was happening only on `userExecutor` (never on `grpcExecutor`, which makes it more strange) in various random test methods in this class.

Thanks!

**update:**

As @Thomas pointed in the comment, `shutdownNow()` returns only tasks that were not even started. In addition to this, `getActiveCount()` should be checked also.

Comment: The [JavaDoc on `shutdownNow()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow()) says: `returns: list of tasks that never commenced execution`. So if waiting for termination times out this should indicate there are still tasks that are being executed at that moment (I'd assume `getActiveCount()` should return a number > 0 in that case).

Comment: @Thomas thanks! I'll try checking this :)

Comment: @Thomas you were right: `getActiveCount()` is always >0 in these cases. (and the reason for the whole thing was probably a bug in test code that caused executor to get just a few ms for termination, not 100 ;-]  I'm now running tests in a loop to check if it keeps happening or not).  
If you bother to convert your comment into an answer, I will gladly mark it as accepted and up-vote  :)  
Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, I'll do that :)

Comment: Also, note that `shutdownNow()` tries to interrupt the worker threads.  But if the tasks don't respond (appropriately) to interrupts, then the workers don't actually shut down.  The executor only will tell you that it has terminated when all of the running tasks have ended ... one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize the comments:

`ThreadPoolExecutor` maintains a queue of not yet and `shutdownNow()` drains that queue and returns its contents. That means you'll only get the tasks that have *not started yet*.

This is consistent with the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#shutdownNow()) which states:

> **Returns:** list of tasks that never commenced execution.

Additionally, there is a set of workers in `ThreadPoolExecutor` (the actual thread pool) which can be queried for the number of active tasks using `ThreadPoolExecutor.getActiveCount()`. That method basically queries each workder to see if it currently has a lock which indicates it is executing a task.

For a more complete picture, have a look at `ThreadPoolExecutor.getTaskCount()`. It adds up a couple of different numbers:

- number of completed tasks reported back to the executor (by workers that got removed)
- number of completed tasks for each existing worker
- +1 for each currently active workder
- the size of the work queue (which is returned by `shutdownNow()`.

It would be great if we'd get access to what the workers are currently executing but I didn't find a way since `workers` (the set of workers) isn't exposed to the outside world and is private and workers don't even seem to hold a reference to the tasks they're executing (at least not directly).

Now `shutdown()` tries to interrupt idle workers, not active ones so `awaitTermination()` might time out due to workers still being active. On the other hand `shutdownNow()` interrupts *all* workers.